# Xcode 13: How to add library search path for "library not found for"

Tags: xcode, react-native

When building a React Native 0.66 project today (used to be working), there is error complaining about library not found for a module which is located at `my-proj/node_modules/aliyun-oss-react-native/`. After `react-native link alien-oss-react-native` and `pod install`, the error remains. [Some post](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2970163) suggests adding search path on `my-proj->Building Setting->Linking` or `Search Paths`. There are quite a few files under `my-proj/node_modules/aliyun-oss-react-native/iOS/`, 2 questions here: 1. which path shall be added to Xcode (such as `my-proj/node_modules/aliyun-oss-react-native/iOS/`)? 2. Shall the path be added to both `Linking` and `Search Paths` in Xcode?

Here is the screen shot of `Search Paths` in Xcode:

[image]

Under `TARGETS`, myproj->Build Settins, `Other Linker Flags`, the module lib which causes error is listed as first one. My guess is that all libs under the `Other Linker Flags` may not be recognized by Xcode. Not sure how this happens.

[image]

Comment: Here is the full error:                                                                                                `ld: library not found for -lAliyunOSSiOS
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`

Comment: Also I can launch the react native app successfully from command line with `nix react-native run-is` even though `build` failed in Xcode

Answer (score 1):

Try to make search paths "recursive".

Comment: After changing all paths to recursive, the error is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The solution works here is open the `myapp.xcworkspace` in Xcode instead of `myapp.xcodeproj`. The build upon workspace went through without any error.

Answer (score 0):

The "library not found" errors occur most of the time because installing the react-native node package and running pod install is often not enough.
The error might go away after running a clean build in xcode using the xcworkspace file. After that running "npm run ios" or "npm start" in your termal should work again.